# Call to a member function load() on null

Tags: laravel, routes

Can someone tell me what to do in this error.
The error is in this line. 'posts' => $author->posts->load('category', 'author')

```
Route::get('/authors/{author:username}', function(User $author){
    
        return view('frontend.posts', [
    
            'title' => 'Post By Author : $author->name',
    
            'posts' => $author->posts->load('category', 'author'),
    
        ]);
    
    });
```

this is my controller

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('frontend.posts', [
            "title" => "All Posts",
            // "posts" => Post::all()
            "posts" => Post::latest()->get()
        ]);
    }

    public function show(Post $post)
    {
        return view('frontend.post', [
            "title" => "Single Post",
            "post" => $post
        ]);
    }

}
```

this is my models

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $with = ['category', 'author'];

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function author(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

and this is my user models

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;


    public function post(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

I have this previous error to "foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given".
I want to display blog posts from certain users.
This is the code from posts.blade.php.

```
        @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <div class="p-t-32">
        <h4 class="p-b-15">
            <a href="/posts/{{ $post->slug }}" 
            class="ltext-108 cl2 hov-cl1 trans-04">
                {{ $post->title }}
            </a>
        </h4>
        <p class="stext-117 cl6">
            {{ $post->excerpt }}
        </p>
        <div class="flex-w flex-sb-m p-t-18">
            <span class="flex-w flex-m stext-111 cl2 p-r-30 m-tb-10">
                <span>
                    <span class="cl4">By</span> <a class="stext-111 cl2 hov-cl1 trans-04" href="/authors/{{ $post->author->username }}">{{ $post->author->name }}</a>  
                    <span class="cl12 m-l-4 m-r-6">|</span>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <a class="stext-111 cl2 hov-cl1 trans-04" href="/categories/{{ $post->category->slug }}">{{ $post->category->name }}</a>
                    <span class="cl12 m-l-4 m-r-6">|</span>
                </span>
                <span>
                    8 Comments
                </span>
            </span>
            <a href="/posts/{{ $post->slug }}" class="stext-101 cl2 hov-cl1 trans-04 m-tb-10">
                Continue Reading
                <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-9"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: This says that `$author->posts` is null. Without information on (a) how `$author` is loaded and how the `posts` relationship is defined (if it even is a relationship, I don't know) we can't help.

Comment: share us your models (author and post) please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the relationship in `User` is `post` but in your controller you used `posts`.

The following should probably work:

```
Route::get('/authors/{author:username}', function(User $author){
    
        return view('frontend.posts', [
    
            'title' => 'Post By Author : $author->name',
    
            'posts' => $author->load('post.category'),
    
        ]);
    
    });
```

Comment: bro thank you so much. i been stress finding this error from 10AM til now. thanks alot bro